# How should i get corresponding field value for taxonomy filed attached?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, database, entities

I use drupal 7. I created a content type with these fields:

1. one field to upload a file to private folder
2. a taxonomy field (for that file)

**my problem:** i can save one file with one taxonomy! but how should i get these data again!(is there any API here) I want to know which taxonomy was saved for a certain file(i need to check it inside my custom module).  i raised similar question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108921/is-there-any-api-to-get-corresponding-field-in-a-custom-content-type/108923#108923): so by following code i can get corresponding field:

```
$nids = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node WHERE title LIKE :title", array(':title' => '%'.$title.'%'))->fetchCol();

$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

foreach($nodes as $node) {

// using field_get_items here automatically loads the field in the correct language
$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_subtitle');
$subtitle = $field_items[0]['safe_value'];
}
```

but it seems it dose not work taxonomy attached field.

**why do i have this question:** i sell some digital files and now i am developing a module for selling my files. *i want to sell them this way:* each file has a certain taxonomy. when my user buys that file he or she gets that taxonomy(and i will keep it in one table). once he clicks on download link i have to check whether that user has that taxonomy already or not! if he has i will let him to download it.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! For which Drupal version are you interested to? There are quite important differences between Drupal 6 and Drupal 7. Then, if you were interested in Drupal 7, is there any reason to query the database instead of using the correct API?

Comment: I edited the question. plz help me if there is any API for loading relevant fields

Comment: So it the taxonomy field attached to the users profile as well as your content type?

Comment: yes. i attach taxonomy to content type but for user just enter them in a separate table. my problem is there with taxonomies and content type. I dont know how to get them

Comment: Why not also attach the taxonomy to the users profile?

Comment: dose it make it easier for look up taxonomy of a certain file? i dont know how to do it exactly and will ask it in another question

Answer (score 0):

You can see the relationship by viewing or editing the node.

If you mean where is this data stored in the DB then if you created a field called file_type then the tid of the associated taxonomy term would be found in the field_data_field_file_type table.

The names of the taxonomy terms are stored in the taxonomy_term_data table.

Comment: It all depends from which Drupal version the OP is using. Then, I don't see why the user would be querying the database directly, on Drupal 7.

Comment: i edited my post and explain why i need to go to my database directly! help me if there is any API in this regard